# About extension on Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open connected with smooth boundary. Let $\zeta$ be a zero extension operator : $\forall u\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$,
 $$\zeta u := \Big\{\begin{array}uu  \quad\text{on $\Omega$},\\0 \quad\text{otherwise.}\end{array}$$ The question is, for which $k$, $\zeta(W^{k,p}(\Omega))\subset W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Here $\Omega$ is not assumed to be bounded.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this fails in the case that $\Omega$ is bounded as we may consider $1\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ and its zero extension is not even weakly differentiable.

Comment: Will this be an answer? : Never. Consider a test function $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\text{supp}(\phi)\cap\partial\Omega\neq\emptyset$. Then $\phi|_\Omega\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for all $k,p\in\mathbb{N}$, but $\zeta \phi|_\Omega$ is not weakly differentiable.

Comment: The property trivially holds for $k = 0$. For $k = 1$ one should have the characterization $u \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ if and only if $\zeta u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$.